# Nyasa for Shiv Rudra mantra "Om Namo Bhagwate Rudraya"

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, vedic-chanting

I have come across this mantra in a book from Shrimali ji. It contains the viniyoga but there is no mention of the nyasa for this mantra. Is it possible that this mantra does not have a nyasa or it was purposely excluded.